# Explanation of parallel arguments of tf.while_loop in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I want to implement an algorithm which allows a parallel implementation in TensorFlow. My question is what the arguments parallel_iterations, swap_memory and maximum_iterations actually do and which are their appropriate values according the situation. Specifically, in the documentation on TensorFlow's site https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop says that parallel_iterations are the number of iterations allowed to run in parallel. Is this number the number of threads? When someone should allow CPU-GPU swap memory and for what reason? What are the advantages and disadvantages from this choice? What is the purpose of maximum_iterations? Can it be combined with parallel_iterations?

Answer (score 1):

**swap_memory** is used when you want to have extra memory on the GPU device. Usually when you are training a model some activations are saved in the GPU mem. for later use. With swap_memory, you can store those activations in the CPU memory and use the GPU mem. to fit e.g. larger batch sizes. And this is an advantage. You would choose this if you need big batch_sizes or have long sequences and want to avoid OOM exceptions. Disadvantage is computation time since you need to transfer the data from CPU mem. to GPU mem.

The **maximum iterations** is smth. like this:

```
while num_iter < 100 and <some condition>:
    do something
    num_iter += 1
```

So it is useful when you check a condition, but also want to have an upper bound (one example is to check if your model converges. If it doesn't you still want to end after k iterations.)

As for **parallel_iterations** I am not sure, but it sounds like multiple threads, yes. You can try and see the effect in a sample script.